# Does using only NAND/NOR gates increase circuit delay?

Tags: manufacturing, delay, digital-logic, performance

I remember learning in school that one can construct any logical circuit from solely `NAND` or `NOR` gates.

First of all, I am wondering if this is how it's actually done: i.e. when Intel makes a CPU, do they build all the registers, etc. using `NAND`/`NOR` gates, or do they have some other fancier way of doing things?

Secondly, I'm wondering if constructing everything in this manner increases propagation delay compared to a circuit made using `AND`/`OR`/`NOT` gates as well.

I know that when using `PMOS`/`NMOS` configurations to build gates, an `AND` or an `OR` comes out as 2 stages as opposed to a `NAND` or a `NOR` which are both only 1.  Since I know you can make an `AND` from 2 cascaded `NAND`s and an `OR` from 2 cascaded `NOR`s, it seems as though propagation delay would not increase as long as manufacturers were using both `NAND`s and `NOR`s.

Does anybody have any insight on all this, especially as to what is really done on manufactured ICs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> First of all, I am wondering if this is how it's actually done: i.e. when Intel makes a CPU, do they build all the registers, etc. using `NAND`/`NOR` gates, or do they have some other fancier way of doing things?

Registers aren't made out of gates, most often they are dedicated circuits. They can be seen as made with inverters (`NOT`), but only to a certain extent.

In CMOS technology, everlogic circuit is based on the inverter: `NOR` and `NAND` gates are just inverters with multiple inputs arranged in a clever way, basically. So the inverting gates are faster than non inverting ones, which are just inverting gates with a `NOT` at the output.

Also in dynamic logic, it's simpler to cascade two inverting blocks than putting `NOT` gates everywhere.

Consider that in some cases a circuit may be made out of separated blocks, so there may be a case in which the output is interfaced through one or more inverters for buffering.

And there is another advantage in that: **integration**. Having a small number of different gates helps in laying out the circuit, and uniforming the performance. Often libraries include logic blocks at different levels of complexity: transistor, gate, operator, or higher.

So, briefly, yes, fast processors are mostly using inverting gates.

Comment: Okay, I think this makes sense to me. As a check - let's say I wanted to make a basic (e.g. 4-bit) adder using combinational logic (i.e. not by linking half-adders). Would I approach this problem trying to use only `NAND` and `NOR` gates, and as few of these as possible? Will this almost always yield a better design (in terms of delay/gate count) than if I approached the problem using a full repertoire of gates and then replaced `AND`/`OR`/`NOT` gates with their `NAND`/`NOR` equivalents?

Comment: @llakais in almost any case, yes. And at least it will be equal. But, for instance, I've designed an adder for a university course, and I've done two things: first, I've used 4:2 adder blocks with full-adders (blocks win!), and second, I've implemented the full-adder with pass transistor XOR gates, so sometimes there are different solutions.

Comment: I will mention that for adders, having a full-adder cell is usually the fastest, not a combination of gates.

Comment: @W5VO well a full adder is basically a combination of an XOR and an AND gate...but indeed the XOR can be made in clever ways without using the basic gates

Answer (score 3):

My inclination with CMOS is to think of a basic building block as being an inverter preceded by an arbitrary combination of independent "and" and "or" gates with no interconnections between them; all of the following functions:

```
not (X and (Y or Z))
not (X or (Y and Z))
not (X and Y and Z)
not (X or Y or Z)
```

have essentially the same cost in silicon, even though only the latter two have names.  Trying to compose the former two functions using some combination of NAND or NOR gates would yield something which was much bigger and slower than a direct realization would be.